# Where does the log file locate in a web application with log4j?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, logging, log4j

With the following settings:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=test.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=info
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Where does the test.log file locate in a java web application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do specify a relative name, it is the working directory of your application server.

Comment: How do I have to do to set it to somewhere inside my web application, given the fact that I don't know the path from my application server to my web application?
Thanks again.

Comment: You can specify in Web.xml the path of the logs 
 <init-param>
      <!-- The Path for the LOG directory of PWM where all log files will be stored. -->
      <param-name>log.path</param-name>
      <param-value>pwm\logs</param-value>
    </init-param>

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that once I put the tags into web.xml and the properties file in src, the location will be myapp\logs\test.log?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify this as a system property and get it Via [System.getProperty()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

what we do is define a property as logroot ie.; **-Dlogroot="PATH_TO_LOGS_FOLDER"**

**EDIT:**  FWIW System.getProperty() checks  for **[checkPropertyAccess](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPropertyAccess%28java.lang.String%29)** as well as **[checkPermission](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkPermission%28java.security.Permission%29)** in case of lack of permissions.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions on this.
1. Where should I define 'logroot="PATH_TO_LOGS_FOLDER"'? in log4j.properties? or do you have a reference link for this?
2. is "PATH_TO_LOGS_FOLDER" a relative path to my webapp root?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are using IDE,typically it is set as a property in the Tomcat->optional vm arguements

Comment: reg 2) it can be absolute/relative path, FWIW, we use to set it as a directory in our workspace(MyEclispe IDE) thus we create a directory inside our web-app root called as logs, it goes there(-Dlogroot="c:/workspace/logs"), thus can access the logroot using the above method in the post